# Any way to solve the issue "CKEDITOR is undefined" while upgrading CKEDITOR to latest version v5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin

I am facing an issue while upgrading CKEDITOR to latest version v5.It is showing some JQuery error while upgrading the version.[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSHSQ.png). Anyone have any idea?

Checking for a solution to solve version upgrading issue of CKEDITOR.

Comment: Please post your code. Without it, we can only guess. It might be that CKEDITOR is not defined anywhere, or that a critical file has not been included, or the inclusion order is wrong, or maybe it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday with my custom build and it was due to the a change in the import statement.

The older version was

```
import { Editor } from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';
```

Whereas the newer version now uses

```
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';
```

Note the lack of curly brackets.

Not sure if this applies to your setup, but it's worth taking a look if one of your imports is perhaps the issue.